# Is the time format in 24-hour format?

Tags: c#, datetime, string.format

I get a time format string passed to me in a string. It could be a standard string like "t", but could be a custom one (containing "HH", etc). How can I find out, that **if displayed it'll be a 12-hour or 24-hour format**? (depending on culture and everything...)

Comment: If it's a _really_ custom string, it could even be both...

Comment: @Rawling: it won't be that custom :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to try a date that you can then examine for a given number in the string, that you'd only expect that way. E.g. whether `2000-01-01T19:00:00Z` resulted in a string containing a `7` or a `9` or both.

To be certain in the face of even strange strings like `"'This valid string will mess you up 79'"`, then you need to examine the string, after obtaining the full version for the given culture info if needed.

The following would also make sense as an extension method on `CultureInfo` or `DateTimeFormatInfo`.

In practice, you can simplify by putting those standard formats that normally include only date-info in the group that returns `None` immediately, but I decided to catch even strangeness there:

```
[Flags]
public enum HourRepType
{
  None = 0,
  Twelve = 1,
  TwentyFour = 2,
  Both = Twelve | TwentyFour
}
public static HourRepType FormatStringHourType(string format, CultureInfo culture = null)
{
  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
    format = "G";//null or empty is treated as general, long time.
  if(culture == null)
    culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;//allow null as a shortcut for this
  if(format.Length == 1)
    switch(format)
    {
      case "O": case "o": case "R": case "r": case "s": case "u":
        return HourRepType.TwentyFour;//always the case for these formats.
      case "m": case "M": case "y": case "Y":
        return HourRepType.None;//always the case for these formats.
      case "d":
          return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
      case "D":
        return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern);
      case "f":
        return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern + " " + culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
      case "F":
        return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern);
      case "g":
        return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + " " + culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
      case "G":
        return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + " " + culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern);
      case "t":
        return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
      case "T":
        return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern);
      default:
        throw new FormatException();
    }
  return CustomFormatStringHourType(format);
}
private static HourRepType CustomFormatStringHourType(string format)
{
  format = new Regex(@"('.*')|("".*"")|(\\.)").Replace(format, "");//remove literals
  if(format.Contains("H"))
    return format.Contains("h") ? HourRepType.Both : HourRepType.TwentyFour;
  return  format.Contains("h") ? HourRepType.Twelve : HourRepType.None;
}
```

Comment: I think your regex might need a tweak. e.g. `HH\'h\'` produces (for 1300) `13'1'` but I think your regex might discard the quoted section.

Comment: @Rawling, no, it evaluates left-to-right and captures the first that matches, so after the replace, `HH\'h\'` produces `HHh` which is correctly identified as containing both 24- and 12-hour elements. (And yes, I did test to be sure).

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: If necessary, turn a standard format string into the selected culture's equivalent custom format string. This uses reflected logic to mimic `DateTime.ToString`.

```
if (formatString.Length == 1)
{        
    // Get formatter for the culture of your choice - e.g. the current culture
    DateTimeFormatInfo fi = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;

    formatString = epf.Invoke(
        null,
        new object[]{
            formatString,
            DateTime.MinValue,
            fi,
            TimeSpan.MinValue});
}
```

Step 2: parse the string to see if it contains 12- or 24- hour specifiers. This is an unfortunate mix of using reflected logic to mimic `DateTime.ToString` as far as possible and custom logic where not possible, but it seems to work OK.

```
for (int i = 0; i < formatString.Length; i++)
{
    char current = formatString[i];
    if (current == '"' || current == '\'') // Skip literal quoted sections
    {
        i += (int)pqs.Invoke(
            null,
            new object[] {
                formatString,
                i,
                new StringBuilder()});
    }
    else if (current == '\\') // Skip escaped characters
    {
        i+= 1;
    }
    else if (current == 'h')
    {
        is12Hour = true;
    }
    else if (current == 'H')
    {
        is24Hour = true;
    }
}
```

This relies on the following two `MethodInfo`s gained by reflection:

```
var t = Assembly
    .GetAssembly(typeof(System.DateTime))
    .GetType("System.DateTimeFormat");
var epf = t.GetMethod(
    "ExpandPredefinedFormat",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var pqs = t.GetMethod(
    "ParseQuoteString",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

The first handles turning a single-character standard format specifier into a multiple-character custom format specifier for a given culture. The second handles quoted literals inside a custom format specifier.

Comment: I've updated this answer to use reflection to emulate `DateTime.ToString` rather than to try to do it yourself.

Comment: @Jon Damn, you're right. Also if there's `\h` in there somewhere.

Comment: And if the implementation changes to not use `ExpandPredefinedFormat` any more, since it isn't documented. See my answer for one that uses public documented methods only.

Comment: @Jon I think I've rectified this, although it's not any prettier. Also relies on reflection further... Dying to see your public-only answer :)

Comment: It's down below on this page. Can't say a switch statement is every elegant in OO languages, but I think it hits all the edge cases.

Comment: @Jon I think it's reasonable enough when you have a nice well-defined list of possibilities like in this case. I did originally have a switch similar to yours, but when I realised each standard format didn't have a dedicated property (e.g. `"f"`) I fell back on reflection rather than follow it though; I didn't notice these were nicely defined on MSDN as combinations of the others.

Comment: Yes, and it's unavoidable in cases like this. The instinct to dislike them is one worth fostering though :)

Answer (score 1):

You could format a known date using the string, one which you know will only contain a particular value if it's using 24 hour time:

```
if ((new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 23, 1, 1)).ToString(formatString).Contains("23"))
    Console.WriteLine("24");
else
    Console.WriteLine("12");
```

Comment: Short of a ridiculous format string (e.g. with a literal `23` in it) this is a nice simple way of doing it, and you could probably harden it further against that kind of idiocy.

Comment: @Rawling - yep. Since posting this, I've been pondering if there's a decent way to protect it from such an input.

Comment: You could try for hours 13-23; remove any explicit 13-23s from the input string...

Comment: @Rawling - if you invoke `.ToString(formatString.Replace("23",""))`, I don't think that there's any way for "23" to appear in the output unless it's a 24 hour format.

Comment: You'd also have to be careful with escaping - the string could have `\2\3` in it which would also output `23`, but if you remove `\2\3` you'd have to be careful that the first `\` wasn't itself escaped...