# .net How do I know 12/24 hour format when I know the culture Info

Tags: .net, time, cultureinfo

In .net, when I know the culture info, how do I know the time format of 12/24 hours? Is there an easy way to detect the culuter info specified time format?

What I need to know is just if the culture should use 12/24 hour time format. I know some cultures could use both 12/24 hour time format. But what's the default time format when we use DateTime.ToShortTimeString()? How do we know the default time format is 12 or 24?

Comment: One sulution is use ShortTimePattern, and check if it contians "tt" specifier. But most of them are not contain "tt". Which means we will use 24 hour time format. Or can we know if a market only support 24 hour time format?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to have a look at the format string:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("cs-CZ").DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern.Contains("H")
```

If the format string contains `H`, it means it's using 24-hour. If it contains `h` or `tt`, though - it's 12-hour.

This is more of a dirty hack than a proper solution, though (and I'm not sure it will work for all cultures - you might need to handle escaping). The question is - why are you even trying to determine the 12/24-hourness? Just use the proper format for the given culture and be done with it.

Comment: It'll probably work, but theoretically there's nothing to say a format couldn't be `"7Hours 34Minutes"` where the `7` is 12-hour. It's also theoretically possible for it to have both 12 and 24 hour in use. You should strip literals and then check for both to be sure.

Comment: @JonHanna Yeah, that's why I said you might need to handle escaping. It's *probably* not going to be an issue, but it might. Stripping those is a bit trickier than it sounds, though :D

Comment: It's not that tricky. See my answer; `new Regex(@"('.*')|("".*"")|(\\.)")` catches them all.

Comment: @JonHanna You forgot about the escaped escape character - `@"\\H"` for `13:00` should resolve as `\13` for example - you will strip the `\H` away. That's why I said it's a bit trickier than it sounds :D And yikes, how annoying the escaping gets once you get to anything a bit more complicated... C# escaping + Regex escaping + DateTime format escaping... ugh.

Comment: No I didn't. Try it. `new Regex(@"('.*')|("".*"")|(\\.)").Replace(@"\\H", "")` returns `H` because it strips out the escaped escape character, so it's correctly identified as being 24-hour.

Comment: (And yes, `new Regex(@"('.*')|("".*"")|(\\.)").Replace(@"\\\H", "")` returns an empty string, as does any other with an odd number of slashes. It comes down to the matching being non-greedy and continuing forwards, so it correctly does the right thing with any number of slashes along with the `'` and `"` literals).

Comment: @JonHanna Ah, right, you're greedily getting the first `\\` instead of going for `\` and `\H`. I wonder if there's still some edge case when this will not work, but it seems it was designed quite well between easy to use and easy to parse. I mean, ignoring the generic formats, which shouldn't be in `ShortTimePattern` IIRC.

Comment: I made myself pretty confident it hit all the edge cases the first time I did it. If you wanted to catch even the generic formats then you could change to calls to `CustomFormatStringHourType` to recursively call `FormatStringHourType` and those would be caught too, but if that did happen there'd be an error in calling `ToShortTimeString()` as it hit on the equivalent recursion, but infinitely too.

Answer (score 0):

It could be both, as there's nothing to prevent a culture using 12 for `ToShortTimeString()` and 24 for `ToLongTimeString()` or vice versa.

However, considering that calling `ToShortTimeString()` is the same as calling `DateTimeFormat.Format(this, "t", DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo)`, the we can then use this with the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12386817/400547):

```
[Flags]
public enum HourRepType
{
  None = 0,
  Twelve = 1,
  TwentyFour = 2,
  Both = Twelve | TwentyFour
}
public static HourRepType FormatStringHourType(string format, CultureInfo culture = null)
{
  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
    format = "G";//null or empty is treated as general, long time.
  if(culture == null)
    culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;//allow null as a shortcut for this
  if(format.Length == 1)
    switch(format)
    {
      case "O": case "o": case "R": case "r": case "s": case "u":
        return HourRepType.TwentyFour;//always the case for these formats.
      case "m": case "M": case "y": case "Y":
        return HourRepType.None;//always the case for these formats.
      case "d":
          return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
      case "D":
        return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern);
      case "f":
        return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern + " " + culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
      case "F":
        return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern);
      case "g":
        return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + " " + culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
      case "G":
        return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + " " + culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern);
      case "t":
        return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
      case "T":
        return CustomFormatStringHourType(culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern);
      default:
        throw new FormatException();
    }
  return CustomFormatStringHourType(format);
}
private static HourRepType CustomFormatStringHourType(string format)
{
  format = new Regex(@"('.*')|("".*"")|(\\.)").Replace(format, "");//remove literals
  if(format.Contains("H"))
    return format.Contains("h") ? HourRepType.Both : HourRepType.TwentyFour;
  return  format.Contains("h") ? HourRepType.Twelve : HourRepType.None;
}
```

And call `FormatStringHourType("t")` to find out whether it's 12 or 24 hours (or possibly neither or both, but that would be strange).

Likewise `FormatStringHourType("T")` would tell us about the long time string.